# Accessing Programatic View from the ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, delegates

Im building my views programatically, but need to refer to the views in my controller for setting properties. I cant see a way to achieve this?

I have a reference to the view as of course the controller inits it, but then i cant access properties for example trying `self.view.textField` as id thought i would.

How do I achieve this? And vice versa how do I do things like setting the views textField to use the controller as its delegate to handle its input?

First time ive not used storyboard where all this was simpler but messier, appreciate any clarification on these issues

Comment: You need to declare properties for your class and store the reference to the views you have created in those properties

Comment: So in the view file i declare the UI at class level, then i can access them, but create the actual views in functions in the view file?

Comment: Yes, just like any other property of your object. Just like you would with `@IBOutlet`s, except you can omit the `@IBOutlet` bit

Comment: Thanks, do i need to init the properties such as var emailTextField = UITextField() or will var emailTextField : UITextField?  work?

Comment: You need to initialise them, either as Alexander showed you or by declaring them as explicltiy or implicitly unwrapped optionals and then assign a value later in your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.

Initialize your UI elements directly in `UIViewController`.

**For example:**

```
    private let yourLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Text"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(yourLabel)
        // Setup constraints for yourLabel
    }
```

Then access `yourLabel` anywhere in the controller code. It works for all the UI components.

**NOTE!**

You can setup all the views not in the controller, but in a separate view. And then add only one view (with other subviews inside) to the controller. You will have access to all subviews using this one view. But the way how you create UI components in the separate view will be the same:

```
     let yourSubView: UILabel = { // any UI component
         let label = UILabel()
         label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         return label
     }()
```

Example of a custom separate `UIView`:

```
class CustomView: UIView { // Separate view. Doesn't make the controller massive

    let yourSubView: UILabel = { // any UI component
         let label = UILabel()
         label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func setupViews() {
        addSubview(yourSubView)
        // Setup yourSubView constraints
    }
}
```

Then you can add `CustomView` to `UIViewController` and access all the subviews of `CustomView`.

Comment: but thats wrong, and break architecture and bloats the VC. You shouldnt be creating your view in the controller

Comment: It works fine. The question of architecture is the second problem. You can setup all the views not in the controller, but in a separate view. And then add only one view (with other subviews inside) to controller. You will have access to all subviews using this one view.

Comment: @jackdm  There is nothing wrong with it.  This is precisely what you would typically do; you may chose to create the UIView directly in a function like `setupViews` rather than use an anonymous function, but this method avoids the use of implicitly unwrapped optionals.  If you don't create views in the view controller, where else are you going to create them?

Comment: you create them in a UIView file so you dont have a horribly bloated VC, the VC is for controlling logic not view design. the revised answer looks more like what id believe

Comment: @jackdm, I updated my answer. Yes, it's better to use custom separate views. But the idea of creating views is the same. No matter where and how many them are.

Comment: @jackdm, sometimes controllers are so small that you don't need to create separate views with subviews in different files .

Comment: You are welcome :) I recommend watching this channel, if you want to create everything programatically: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA